# Sorting the string [ ] manually which is filled by office.interop.excel in C#

Tags: c#, string, sorting, office-interop

I am reading sheet names from excel file using `interop.excel`. And adding sheet names to string array. I want to sort the strings array manually. Like I have values in string array.

- G 7
- G 4
- G 6
- Nur
- G 1
- ECE

I want to sort it like

- ECE
- Nur
- G 1
- G 4
- G 6
- G 7

Code is under.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = 
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open(openFileExcel.FileName);

string[] xlSheets = new string[xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count];
int i = 0;

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet in xlWorkBook.Worksheets)
{
    xlSheets[i] = wSheet.Name;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what rules you're using for the desired sorting algorithm. What are they?

Comment: I want that the `ECE` `Nur` at top 1,2 position respectively. After that `G` 1 4 6 7 values at 3,4,5,6 position.

Comment: I haven't used any rules. Didn't know which algorithm works.

Comment: There must be some reason you want `ECE` before `Nur`. What is the logic behind that reason? It would be trivial (though not necessarily useful) to hard-code the results in the order you've specified. But if you want to do it programmatically on varying sets of data, you need some logic that determines the sort order. Once you define that, then we can apply the logic to the array for sorting.

Comment: These are school Class Names. ECE is starting class. Nur is after ECE.

Comment: Please take a few minutes and think about how to solve this problem. How do you know that `ECE` is the starting class? Do you have the start times stored somewhere? If so, then we can easily sort by `StartTime`. Hopefully you see where I'm going with this. We need to have the information available that determines the order. Otherwise just hard-code it. If you want a hard-coded answer, we can help with that, too.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments we've determined that you want to sort by a class numbering system, but it's not clear if that information is available. Please update the question if it is, and we can provide a better answer.

But in the meantime, here's a way to "hard-code" the order, by creating an array of known items in the deisred order, and then using `OrderBy` (from `System.Linq`) to order the items from excel by their index in the ordered array. Any items that aren't in our "ordered array" are placed at the end in their original order:

```
// This array contains the desired order of known items
string[] orderedNames = 
{
    "ECE", "Nur", "G 1", "G 4", "G 6", "G 7",
};

// This array comes from Excel, and is not in the order we desire
string[] xlSheets = 
{
    "G 7", "G 4", "G 6", "Nur", "G 1", "ECE",
};

// Here we sort by the index of the item in the orderedNames array. Any items 
// that aren't in that array are added to the end, in their original order
xlSheets = xlSheets
    .OrderBy(name => orderedNames.Contains(name)  // If the name is in our ordered array
        ? Array.IndexOf(orderedNames, name)  // Then order by it's index in the array
        : orderedNames.Length)  // Else use a number greater than the count of known items
    .ToArray();
```

An alternate way to write this is to first `OrderByDecending` on whether or not the item is in the array (`true` will come first, so items NOT in the array will be last), and `ThenBy` their index in the ordered array:

```
xlSheets = xlSheets
    .OrderByDescending(name => orderedNames.Contains(name))
    .ThenBy(name => Array.IndexOf(orderedNames, name))
    .ToArray();
```

Notice that in both cases we have to consider whether or not the item is in the array. This is because `Array.IndexOf` will return `-1` if an item is not found, and that will put the "not found" items *before* the "found" items, which we don't want.

Comment: No its not the class start time it is numbering. These are the class in the school in which students are enrolled

Comment: Ok, updated answer. You still haven't told us if the associated numbering is available to us in code so we can use it to sort the list, so otherwise the answer remains the same.

Comment: I am retrieving sheet names of Excel workbook sheets. Pls tell me is there a way to assign number to Excel sheets??

Answer (score 1):

Assign a number to the two categories of items. `ECE` and `Nur` => 0, all the other ones => 1. Then sort by this number first and by the string next.

```
xlSheets = xlSheets
    .OrderBy(s => s == "ECE" || s == "Nur" ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(s => s)
    .ToArray();
```